# Can't find Weight transfer in 2.8

Tags: rigging

Any idea where the ability to transfer weights is located in blender 2.8? I can't find where they moved it after looking around, and a bunch of google searches.

Comment: maybe you're looking for the Data Transfer modifier? Last answer on this page: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51589/clothes-weight-paint-skinning/98967#98967

Comment: In object mode, menu "object/relations/transfer mesh data".